# Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED - REACT-NATIVE - ANDROID-STUDIO

Tags: react-native, android-studio

im trying to run the app in my real device using android studio, eveything is ready and correct, but when i run `react-native run-android` it will first says connect to the server but then this error appears:

[image]

want to use the device as debugger

Comment: So you have a react native app, and you want to debug it on a physical device?

Comment: yes, because using expo i cant load third libraries, so i need to run in with android emulator and debug it in real devices

Answer (score 0):

For running expo apps, you would normally do this using the command line.

Navigate to the root of your project, then (if you still have all the defaults set) you should be able to open a terminal in that directory and type `npm run start`. This will start the metro bundler and the other react native tools.

The first time doing this might take a while, but when it's done, you should see a QR code. Scan it with your device, you should be prompted to download the expo app and then your application will run on your phone. You only need to download the expo app once, and all the apps you develop using expo will run on it.

I'm not totally sure if this answers your question, but I hope this helped.

*note that this assumes that you have and use npm, the process is slightly different for yarn and other package managers. If npm run start doesn't work for you, make sure you have npm in the PATH variable, and check the package.json file. You should see an entry in scripts - "start": "expo start". You need to type npm run then whatever your key is for the script that has a value of "expo start"